# Node.js Authentication TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-authentication

I'm currently following a [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/http-authentication-in-node-js/) on how to build a simple HTTP authentication system in Node.js. I've followed pretty much all the steps of the tutorial just as it says, yet when I try to run it, I always get this error: `TypeError: object is not a function`.

Here's the code from the tutorial. This error occurs on line 3.

```
var http = require("http");
var auth = require("http-auth");
var digest = auth({
  authRealm: "Private area",
  authFile: __dirname + "/htpasswd",
  authType: "digest"
});
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  digest.apply(request, response, function(username) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello " + username);
    response.end();
  });
});

server.listen(80);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mentioning which LINE you get the error on is always a good hint, BTW.  Really helps other people who are looking at the code.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher updated!

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
var basic = auth.basic({
  authRealm: "Private area",
  authFile: __dirname + "/htpasswd",
  authType: "digest"
});
```

for the assignment of the `basic` variable.

Comment: Seems like there's some sort of issue with this module. I tried using that solution but it says that the method "apply" (which I used later on in this code) doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess that's totally another error. The issue might be with the tutorial, not necessarily with the module. The tutorial is more than 3 years old

Comment: True- I might have to look into alternatives.